# Examples of "total cancellation functions" $f_Q(n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $f_Q(n):\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a series of arithmetic functions for every real value $Q$, for which the expected values $\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[f_Q(n)]$ all exist. Here we are defining $\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by

$$\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[f(n)]=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-1}\sum_{n<x}f(n)$$

We say that $f_Q(n)$ is a **total cancellation function** if, for any bounded sequence $(a_n)$, it holds that $\lim_{Q\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_nf_Q(n)]=0$ provided that the expected values the limit is being taken over all exist.

I've been messing around for a while trying find examples of total cancellation functions, and the only example I have discovered is the functions $f_Q(n)=\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ d<Q}}\mu(d)$ where $\mu(d)$ is the Mobius function.

Finding more examples might be interesting as it could lead to conjectures or theorems about conditions functions $f_Q(n)$ must have to be total cancellation.

Comment: How would you prove that the functions $f_Q$ derived from $\mu$ have the desired property?

Comment: @Wojowu It is a corollary of this (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375778/prove-or-disprove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-lambdan-mathbbe-n-in-math) MO question of mine, where the order of summation in the expected value and the outer summation is changed (and $\lambda(n)$ is replaced by $\mu(n)$, which is not a gap that is too hard to jump)

Comment: Also needs definition of $\mathbb E_{n \in \mathbb N}$.